# OAuthSwift closure Capturing values not working

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, closures, handler

```
func queryProducts() -> Array<String> {
var final = [String]()
var temp  = [String]()
self.oauthswift.client.get("http://api.v3.factual.com/t/products-cpg?q=coke",
    success: {
        (data, response) in
        let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let json = JSON(data: data)


        if json["status"].stringValue == "ok" {
            // we're OK to parse!
            for result in json["response"]["data"].arrayValue {
                final.append(result["product_name"].stringValue)

            }

        }
          temp = final

    }

    , failure: { error in
        print(error)
    })


return temp

}
```

Hey everyone, New to swift and I've been trying to capture values from this successhandler but it seems like nothing is working. Inside the closure I'm able to print the array I want.

In the end, I'm trying to return the array final with all the product names appended.

What it should return :
["Cola Diet Plus", "Zero Sixer", "Cola Diet Sweetened With Splenda", "Cola Diet", "Coke Diet", "Cola Diet Cherry", "Cola Diet With Lemon", "Cola Diet Twin Pack", "Cola Vanilla", "Cola Diet Vanilla", "Cola Diet", "Cola Diet With Lemon", "Cola Diet Caffeine Free", "Cola Diet With Lemon", "Coca-Cola", "Cola Diet Caffeine Free", "Cola Diet With Lime", "Fountain Syrup Diet", "Cola Diet", "Cola Diet With Lemon"]

What it returns:
[]

Any suggestions would be amazing!

Comment: You must understand that: The closure run in another thread. So the line `return temp` will be run before the code in `closure` run. So, see the answer of `anhtu` below, and use that way. I just explain why we have to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not return like that. You have to using closure.

```
    func queryProducts(successCallback: ([String])->Void) {
        var final = [String]()
        var temp  = [String]()
        self.oauthswift.client.get("http://api.v3.factual.com/t/products-cpg?q=coke",
            success: {
                (data, response) in
                let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                let json = JSON(data: data)


                if json["status"].stringValue == "ok" {
                    // we're OK to parse!
                    for result in json["response"]["data"].arrayValue {
                        final.append(result["product_name"].stringValue)

                    }

                }
                temp = final
                successCallback(temp) // callback here

            }

            , failure: { error in
                print(error)
            })

     }
```

Then you can call like:

```
queryProducts() {
    arrayProducts in
    // doing something, arrayProduct is temp array
}
```